# Как установить JSON Path Extractor в JMeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

Выдает ошибки:

> Cannot find class: com/jayway/jsonpath/PathNotFoundException
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/PathNotFoundException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из ошибки очевидно, что не найден класс `com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException`

Проверьте лежит ли в `CLASSPATH` библиотека [JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath). Если она отсутствует - скачайте [её jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/2.0.0) и положите в `CLASSPATH`. Поскольку вы не указали версию JMeter и JSON Path Extractor, вероятно, придется поиграться с версиями.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы пытаетесь открыть тест-план третьей версии JMeter вторым. 
Поддержка JSON Path [появилась](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html#New%20and%20Noteworthy) лишь в 3.0, попробуйте последнюю версию.